# Removing a specific element from array through user input

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I am a bit new to arrays and I'm wondering how I can ask a user to input which movie they want to remove from the list of available movies and then how to return a new list that bumps each other movie up one spot. I've watched a bunch of videos but I can't figure it out.. :( It will ask me to enter my username, then show me the menu options. But once I press 3, it does not ask me which movie I would like to delete and it does not remove a movie from the array

```
 package practice;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Practice {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
         List<String> allowedUsernames = Arrays.asList("John", "Sam", "Lucy", "Arthur", "Trisha");
         System.out.println("Welcome to the Java movie rental store! To start, please enter your username!");

         String name = "";
        
         do {
             if (!name.equals("")) {
                 System.out.println("Please enter a valid username.");
             }

             name = input.nextLine();
         } while (!allowedUsernames.contains(name));
                
         System.out.println("Hello " +name+ "! Please select from the following menu options!");
        
         getchoices();
     }
    
     public static void getchoices() {  
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
         String[] optionslist = {
             "1) See full list of movies",
             "2) Add a movie",
             "3) Delete a movie",
             "4) Modify a movie",
             "5) Exit"
         };
        
         for (int i = 0; i < optionslist.length; i++) {
             System.out.println(optionslist[i]);
         }
        
         int number = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.println("You selected: " + optionslist[number-1].substring(3, optionslist[number - 1].length()));
         movieList();
     }
     
     public static void printNewMovielist() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String[] newList = {
             "Shrek",
             "Beauty and the Beast",
             "Wall-E",
             "Cinderella",
             "Alice in Wonderland"
         };
    
         System.out.println("Movies Available: ");
         newMovieList(newList);
    
         newList = deleteMovies(newList); 
         System.out.println("The updates list of movies available at the rental store: ");
         newMovieList(newList); 
         deleteMovies(newList); 
     }

     public static void movieList() {   
         ArrayList<String> Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
        
         System.out.println("Movies Available:");
        
         Movies.add("Shrek");
         Movies.add("Beauty and the Beast");
         Movies.add("Wall-E");
         Movies.add("Cinderella");
         Movies.add("Alice in Wonderland");
        
         for (int i = 0; i <Movies.size(); i++) {
             System.out.println(Movies.get(i));
         }
     }

     public static String[] deleteMovies (String [] newList) { 
         String[] deleteMovie = new String [newList.length - 1]; 
    
         for (int i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) { 
             deleteMovie[i] = newList[i]; 
         }
    
         Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in); 
         System.out.println("Which movie would you like to delete?"); 
    
         return deleteMovie; 
     }

     public static void newMovieList(String [] newList) { 
         for (int i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) { 
             System.out.println((i - 1) + " )" + newList[i]);   
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static String[] deleteMovies(String[] newList) {
    String[] deleteMovie = new String[newList.length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
        deleteMovie[i] = newList[i];
    }

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which movie would you like to delete?");

    return deleteMovie;
}
```

You can see above that `sc` is not used. You create the scanner but you don't ask the user for a `nextLine()`! Contrast this with how you did it with the `input` scanner. Therefore, your program will exit because it finished (it's not waiting for a `nextLine()` from the user).

**Edit:** As K450 pointed out in the comments, you don't even reach this above point in the code. You simply print out which option they select, and then list all movies, and that's all. If your program sees that the user tries to delete a movie (entered that option), you should call this method.

To "remove" an element from an array by shifting everything, you can create an array of length `n - 1` similar to what you did, but then note that the index of all elements after the removed element in the original array will be one greater than where it should be copied in the new array.

For example, if you'd like to delete `Sam` in the array:

`["John", "Sam", "Mary"]`

Then you would want `

```
newArray[0] = oldArray[0];
newArray[1] = oldArray[2];
```

There are ways to do this without using a for loop, but I would suggest at least attempting it as an exercise. A better option would probably be an `ArrayList` for your use case though, since you can easily remove an element at an index.

Comment: OP's code don't even reach `deleteMovies` function. As they have not mapped user's choice with appropriate functions at first place. Their code exits from `movieList()`.